# merge tags error

Tags: support, tagging, tag-synonyms

I was attempting to merge two tags (`mercedes` & `mercedes-benz`) and receieved the following error:

```
MergeTags(mercedes-benz, mercedes) encountered the following exception:

tag mercedes-benz doesn't exist in the Tags table.

System.ApplicationException: tag mercedes-benz doesn't exist in the Tags table. ---> System.ApplicationException: tag mercedes-benz doesn't exist in the Tags table.
   at StackOverflow.Models.Tag.MergeTags(String mastertag, String removetag, User user, Boolean ensuresynonym) in c:\builds\StackExchange-Network\prod\source\StackOverflow\Models\Tag.cs:line 1786
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at StackOverflow.Models.Tag.MergeTags(String mastertag, String removetag, User user, Boolean ensuresynonym) in c:\builds\StackExchange-Network\prod\source\StackOverflow\Models\Tag.cs:line 1910
   at StackOverflow.Controllers.AdminController.MergeTags(String mastertag, String removetag, Nullable`1 approve, Nullable`1 ensuresynonym) in c:\builds\StackExchange Network\prod\source\StackOverflow\Controllers\AdminController.Merge.cs:line 132
```

I was having to do this merge since I created the tag synonym of Master `mercedes-benz` <- Synonym `mercedes` and `mercedes-benz` was not an available tag while tagging a question.
[image: mercedes tag options]

Comment: p.s. this is a moderator only function so discussing it won't be very useful to 99% of the potential audience.

Comment: @JeffAtwood where should I report moderator level bugs?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you must force the tag to exist first. **You can't merge into nonexistent tags.**

So edit a question and add the tag, *then* do the merge.

Comment: the tag was in use when I created the tag synonym, I didn't realize I had to re-add the tag into the system.